# Winform controls for C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am starting a new project and I need some very pretty controls. The ones that come with VS2010 aren't going to cut it.

This application will be very simple, but I want it to look very appealing.

Any suggestions for 3rd party controls that can help me do that?

Open source or pay.

Comment: Why not use WPF? That's *way* more sexy than WinForms.

Comment: Very interesting that the first four answers all cite the same three vendors.

Comment: Stay away from infragistics, as they tend to be completely bloated - I was thrilled to move away from it (even after 3 or so years of subscription) and moved to devx.

Comment: I just tried to see what tabs contain the letters 'sexy'

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are a number of big suppliers:

http://www.telerik.com

http://www.infragistics.com

http://www.devexpress.com

http://www.componentfactory.com - Krypton Suite

All of these have WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET and Silverlight controls so you can choose how you build your application.

You'll find full pricing info on their sites - I won't quote it here as it will become out of date very quickly.

You might even find some specific controls on [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com).

Comment: +1 for Telerik. They do have their bugs here and they're, but they post new builds every month or so and they make their source code available in some of the packages. Overall their controls have given my team a lot of options for making our projects look professional.

Answer (score 3):

If you want something completely sexy, I am afraid that you'll have to hit the `Graphics` yourself.

All the control suites are generalized and for 'all purpose'.  To create something really unique, well, no control suite should give you what you need.

Answer (score 2):

The most popular ones are

- [**www.telerik.com**](http://www.telerik.com)
- [**www.infragistics.com**](http://www.infragistics.com) and
- [**www.devexpress.com**](http://www.devexpress.com)

Answer (score 2):

These guys sell a really cool GridView I use extensively:

http://www.divelements.co.uk/

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at DevExpress?  http://www.devexpress.com/  There stuff works very well, the look and feel is very customizable.